# How to preserve custom row heights when adding a column? [Tabulator 4.1]

Tags: angular, tabulator

I have a tabulator table where I allow the user to manually adjust the row heights and column widths. They are also able to add/delete rows and columns.

My issue is when after resizing some row heights, you add a column and I guess it repaints the table, therefore resetting the heights of the rows. How can I get around this?

This is how I am adding a new column:

```
this.tabulator.addColumn({
  title: "new" + this.tabulator.getColumns().length, 
  field: "new" + this.tabulator.getColumns().length,
  width: 100,
  editor: "customTextAreaEditor", 
  formatter: this.customTextareaFormatter, 
  sorter: "string", headerSort: false, editableTitle: true
});
```

I am not calling repaint after this.

Comment: That is definitly a BUG in Tabulator, could you create an issue on GitHub and i will look into fixing it for the next patch release.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Oli. I have made an issue on GitHub as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this issue to the Tabulator master branch and will include it in the 4.2.2 patch release later today

Answer (score 0):

You should store those values in your main component and pass them to the cell items. The complexity will depend on how you allow your users to customize the layout (same width for all cells, separate, etc...).

You could store all values in an array for example and pass those values in your *ngFor loop.

Comment: Do you mean store the (resized) widths of the rows before adding a columns and then using these values to repaint the table? I have played around with this. Initially it works great but after trying to add a column again it reverts the rows back to the default heights.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the row heights in your own object and reference the values in a `rowFormatter` callback to reset the height on `row.getElement()`.